# Probability that $N$ dice were rolled given that a five was rolled $n$ times

Tags: probability, dice

I know of the standard way to solve probability questions like the following:

> If a die is rolled 12 times, what is the probability of rolling 4 sixes?

But I want to consider the reverse case:

> If someone preformed an experiment with a die, and they told us that in the experiment the number six came up 4 times, then what is the probability the die was rolled 12 times?

I would like to start with the general case only in a binomial probability. So what I am trying to solve is the following:

> Given an event with two possible outcomes, $A$ with probability $p$ and $B$ with probability $1-p$, what is the probability that the experiment was preformed $N$ times given that $A$ has occurred $n$ times?

Comment: A classic problem in conditional Bayesian analysis.  Google it.

Comment: Did the experiment stop when the six appeared for the $4$th time? If not, then why did the experiment stop?

Comment: Your second last line has $p$ as a probability while your last line has $p$ as an integer

Comment: Well the point is, they don't tell you when the experiment stopped. The question is to determine the probability of the experiment stopping after N trials. And I changed that p to an n, sorry.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the probability", unless you have a probability model for how the experimenter decided how many times to do the experiment.  In Bayesian language, you need a prior.

Comment: To put Robert's point in a more explicit light, suppose that the experimenter is *a priori* equally likely to roll the die $3$ times or $12$ times.  Under such circumstances, the probability that it was rolled $12$ times would be $1$, since $3$ rolls do not suffice to produce $4$ sixes.  On the other hand, if the experimenter is *a priori* equally likely to roll the die $12$ times or $24$ times, then it would be more likely that the experimenter rolled it $24$ times (about $0.7$ as compared to $0.3$ for $12$ times).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is poorly worded.  I'm interpreting as the following:

**Problem**

What is the expected number of rolls of a fair six-sided die until exactly $4$ $5$s appear?

**Solution**

Start by asking:  What is the probability that you stop after exactly $n$ rolls?

The only way you stop after exactly $n$ rolls is if you roll exactly $3$ $5$s in $n-1$ rolls, and a $5$ on the final ($n$th) roll.  That probability is:

$$P(stop\ at\ n) = P(three\ 5s\ after\ n-1\ rolls) P(a\ 5\ on\ roll\ n) =$$

$$\left( {n-1 \choose 3}(1/6)^3 (5/6)^{n - 1 - 3} \right) \cdot {1 \over 6}$$

Here's a graph of that probability.  Notice that the value is $0$ for $n<4$ (of course).

[image]

Now you want to calculated the *expected value* of $n$.  So multiply the probability you stop at $n$ times the value $n$ itself, and sum up over all possible values of $3<n<\infty$.

$$\sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty n \left( {n-1 \choose 3}(1/6)^3 (5/6)^{n - 1 - 3} \right) \cdot {1 \over 6} = 24.$$

The expected value is $24$... which of course makes sense!